# Why odata Trippinservice returns only 8 pages?

Tags: pagination, odata, paging, odata-v4

When I give the odata service url,https://services.odata.org/V4/(S(ysqt4lcalbsipb1qkoc04ryb))/TripPinServiceRW/People in browser,I only get 8 records.Why do I get only 8 records when there are total of 20 records in People entity?Is PageSize set in Trippinservice?Can anyone help me to understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this service implements server-side paging.

Firstly we identify that server-side pagination is in effect from the presense of the `@odata.nextLink` property in the response, this is in the root of the response:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(ysqt4lcalbsipb1qkoc04ryb))/TripPinServiceRW/$metadata#People",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://services.odata.org/V4/(S(ysqt4lcalbsipb1qkoc04ryb))/TripPinServiceRW/People?%24skiptoken=8",
    "value": [
        ... 8 records ... 
    ]
}
```

We can only *assUme* that the page size is `8` by counting the number of records in the response or by consulting the documentation for the given service. In this case there is a `$skiptoken` query parameter inside the *next link*, in this case it happens to have a value of `8` and this corresponds to the number of records, but only by coincidence.
***NOTE:** `%24` is a dollar sign `$` that has been url encoded*

```
~/TripPinServiceRW/People?%24skiptoken=8
```

In the case of the [TripPin](https://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW) service documented in the [OData Basic Tutorial](https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/), the `$skiptoken` value represents the number of records to *skip* and is a *common* implementation, but it is not a *standard*.

> There is no specific mention of the server page size for the `People` feed in the documentation, nor is there a standard way to document `$skiptoken` logic at all in the *$metatdata*. Have a read on *how* and *why* ASP.NET WebAPI implements `skiptoken`: [Use $skiptoken for server-driven paging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/skiptoken-for-server-side-paging)

We can demonstrate this by navigating the next *nextLink* or altering the `$orderby`:

GET: [~/TripPinServiceRW/People?$skiptoken=8](https://services.odata.org/V4/(S(ysqt4lcalbsipb1qkoc04ryb))/TripPinServiceRW/People?$skiptoken=8)

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(ysqt4lcalbsipb1qkoc04ryb))/TripPinServiceRW/$metadata#People",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://services.odata.org/V4/(S(ysqt4lcalbsipb1qkoc04ryb))/TripPinServiceRW/People?%24skiptoken=16",
    "value": [
        ... 8 more records ...
    ]
}
```

The `$skiptoken` is now `16` in the new *nextLink*: `~/TripPinServiceRW/People?%24skiptoken=16`. In many implementations the `$skiptoken` will represent the *key* value of the last record that was sent, but *TripPin* does not use this convention, we can verify that by changing the order:

> Both of these responses will have `$skiptoken=8` in the **nextLink**

GET: [~/TripPinServiceRW/People?$orderby=UserName](https://services.odata.org/V4/(S(ysqt4lcalbsipb1qkoc04ryb))/TripPinServiceRW/People?$orderby=UserName)

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(ysqt4lcalbsipb1qkoc04ryb))/TripPinServiceRW/$metadata#People",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://services.odata.org/V4/(S(ysqt4lcalbsipb1qkoc04ryb))/TripPinServiceRW/People?%24orderby=UserName&%24skiptoken=8",
    "value": [
        ... 8 records ...
    ]
}
```

GET: [~/TripPinServiceRW/People?$orderby=UserName desc](https://services.odata.org/V4/(S(ysqt4lcalbsipb1qkoc04ryb))/TripPinServiceRW/People?$orderby=UserName%20desc)

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(ysqt4lcalbsipb1qkoc04ryb))/TripPinServiceRW/$metadata#People",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://services.odata.org/V4/(S(ysqt4lcalbsipb1qkoc04ryb))/TripPinServiceRW/People?%24orderby=UserName+desc&%24skiptoken=8",
    "value": [
        ... 8 records ...
    ]
}
```

According to the specification, `$skiptoken` is an arbitrary token that services can use to retrieve the *next* page of data from a previously prepared set. The value of the `$skiptoken` will have special significance to the server itself and it may be an arbitrary token or reference pointing to a page in a *cached* resultset.

> **[11.2.5.7 Server-Driven Paging](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part1-protocol.html#_Server-Driven_Paging)**
> Responses that include only a partial set of the items identified by the request URL MUST contain a link that allows retrieving the next partial set of items. This link is called a *next link*; its representation is format-specific. The final partial set of items MUST NOT contain a next link.
>
> OData clients MUST treat the URL of the next link as *opaque*, and MUST NOT append system query options to the URL of a next link. Services may not allow a change of format on requests for subsequent pages using the next link. Clients therefore SHOULD request the same format on subsequent page requests using a compatible `Accept` header. OData services may use the reserved system query option `$skiptoken` when building next links. Its content is opaque, service-specific, and must only follow the rules for URL query parts.

It is worth highlighting this very specific note in the specification:

> OData clients MUST NOT use the system query option $skiptoken when constructing requests.

The `$skiptoken` is a *server-side* implementation and in many cases you couldn't even guess what a correct value might be. The TripPin service is a very simple demonstration API, it uses a page size of 8 to illustrate the behaviour of server-side paging, given the small size of the overall dataset (20) this is a nice arbitrary number that will result in multiple pages with the last page only partially full. That's enough to test basic compliance of server-side supporting data interfaces.

Server-side paging is designed to encourage *search driven* interfaces where users formulate more precise search criteria in preference to *browsing* through the pages 1 by 1. [Virtual Scrolling](https://blog.logrocket.com/virtual-scrolling-core-principles-and-basic-implementation-in-react/) is a common user interface paradigm that exploits server-side paging. Different languages and runtimes have different implementations but basically the user can scroll through a list or grid of data and when they get to the bottom there might be a link to "load more" records (behind the scenes, this will load the response from the *nextLink*). Sometimes this link is not displayed and the data is automatically loaded as the user approaches or reaches the end of the list.

You can still use traditional *client-side* paging using the `$top` and `$skip` query parameters, however some service implementations of *server-side* paging will still constrain the results to the fixed number of rows as defined by that servers internal logic. If you are implementing *client-side* paging then you may still need to use the *nextLink* to retrieve all the results for each *client-side* page of results.

Lets compare by first getting page 2, of a *client-side* page size of 5:

GET: [~/TripPinServiceRW/People?$skip=5&$top=5](https://services.odata.org/V4/(S(ysqt4lcalbsipb1qkoc04ryb))/TripPinServiceRW/People?$skip=5&$top=5)

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(ysqt4lcalbsipb1qkoc04ryb))/TripPinServiceRW/$metadata#People",
    "value": [
        ... 5 records ...
    ]
}
```

Notice that there is no `@odata.nextLink` property in the response, that is because the requested number of items does not exceed the server page size logic. So lets try a page size of 9. This time, to retrieve all the records for the page, we will need to make multiple queries.

> The general guidance here is to recursively call the service for each of the *nextLink* urls in the responses, if they contain a *nextLink*

GET: [~/TripPinServiceRW/People?$skip=9&$top=9](https://services.odata.org/V4/(S(ysqt4lcalbsipb1qkoc04ryb))/TripPinServiceRW/People?$skip=9&$top=9)

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(ysqt4lcalbsipb1qkoc04ryb))/TripPinServiceRW/$metadata#People",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://services.odata.org/V4/(S(ysqt4lcalbsipb1qkoc04ryb))/TripPinServiceRW/People?%24skip=9&%24top=9&%24skiptoken=8",
    "value": [
        ... 8 records ...
    ]
}
```

GET: [~/TripPinServiceRW/People?%24skip=9&%24top=9&%24skiptoken=8](https://services.odata.org/V4/(S(ysqt4lcalbsipb1qkoc04ryb))/TripPinServiceRW/People?%24skip=9&%24top=9&%24skiptoken=8)

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(ysqt4lcalbsipb1qkoc04ryb))/TripPinServiceRW/$metadata#People",
    "value": [
        ... 1 record ...
    ]
}
```

When you are implementing your own OData-v4 conformant API it is important to understand this *quirk* and to document specifically in your API documentation what your policy or convention is with regard to *server-side* paging and which collections it is enabled on.

> In my own implementations, I will often *disable* server-side paging if the request contains the *client-paging* token `$top` (and the value for `$top` is <= `200`) but

From a *client-side* implementation if you see a *nextLink* property in the response and you didn't recieve the expected number of records, then you should query for the subsequent *server-pages* to fulfil your request if you are not able to implement a *virtual Scroll* enabled user experience.

---

<sub>**NOTE:** Normally when we discuss paging in OData v4 services the examples would include use of the `$count` query option.</sub>

> <sub>**[11.2.9 Requesting the Number of Items in a Collection]**: On success, the response body MUST contain the exact count of items matching the request after applying any `$filter` or `$search` system query options...</sub>
>
> <sub>The returned count MUST NOT be affected by `$top`, `$skip`, `$orderby`, or `$expand`.</sub>

<sub>The TripPin service **DOES NOT CONFORM** to this particular (and many other) clause in the specification, so I have not used that query option in this explanation.</sub>